# Save results as dataframes in a pyspark multi-output-loop

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, pyspark

I have three pyspark dataframes. I want to put the dataset reference in a dictionary, write a loop, perform some operations on these three dataframes, and then save them for further analysis. But I struggle with the last step. I have two questions:

1. In my code below, how do I access the results in `TRANSFORMS`? When I type: `print(TRANSFORMS[0])`
   I only get this cryptic result:
   `<function __main__.multi_output(Input_table, table_name='ONE')>`
   Is there a mistake in my code and the transormations are never made?
2. How do I modify the function so it saves three datasets like `df_1_result, df_2_result, df_3_result` which I can then later use in further analysis?

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Sparky').getOrCreate()


# Create the initial dataframe
data = [("James","M",60000),("Michael","M",70000),
        ("Robert",None,400000),("Maria","F",500000),
        ("Jen","",None)]
columns = ["name","gender","salary"]
df_when = spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema = columns)

# Create three identical datasets
df_1 = df_when
df_2 = df_when
df_3 = df_when


TRANSFORMS = []

DATASETS = {
    "ONE"   : df_1,
    "TWO"   : df_2,
    "THREE" : df_3,
    }

for table_name, table_location in list(DATASETS.items()):
    def multi_output(Input_table, table_name=table_name):
        if table_name=="ONE":
            output_table = Input_table.drop("name")
        
        elif table_name=="TWO":
            output_table== Input_table.drop("gender")
        
        elif table_name=="THREE":
            output_table = Input_table.drop("salary")
        
        return output_table
    
    TRANSFORMS.append(multi_output)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here:

Issue 1:     TRANSFORMS.append(multi_output) simply adds the function definition to the TRANSFORMS list. The function is never invoked. Also, we should define it outside the for-loop.

Issue 2: The statement under the second condition has a typo.
The code below, should work as expected.

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Sparky').getOrCreate()


# Create the initial dataframe
data = [("James","M",60000),("Michael","M",70000),
        ("Robert",None,400000),("Maria","F",500000),
        ("Jen","",None)]
columns = ["name","gender","salary"]
df_when = spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema = columns)

# Create three identical datasets
df_1 = df_when
df_2 = df_when
df_3 = df_when


TRANSFORMS = []

DATASETS = {
    "ONE"   : df_1,
    "TWO"   : df_2,
    "THREE" : df_3,
    }

def multi_output(Input_table, table_name):
        output_table = Input_table
        if table_name=="ONE":
            output_table = Input_table.drop("name")
        
        elif table_name=="TWO":
            output_table= Input_table.drop("gender")
        
        elif table_name=="THREE":
            output_table = Input_table.drop("salary")
        
        return output_table
      
for table_name, table_location in list(DATASETS.items()):
    TRANSFORMS.append(multi_output(table_location,table_name))
    
len(TRANSFORMS)
TRANSFORMS[0].show()
TRANSFORMS[1].show()
TRANSFORMS[2].show()

+------+------+
|gender|salary|
+------+------+
|     M| 60000|
|     M| 70000|
|  null|400000|
|     F|500000|
|      |  null|
+------+------+

+-------+------+
|   name|salary|
+-------+------+
|  James| 60000|
|Michael| 70000|
| Robert|400000|
|  Maria|500000|
|    Jen|  null|
+-------+------+

+-------+------+
|   name|gender|
+-------+------+
|  James|     M|
|Michael|     M|
| Robert|  null|
|  Maria|     F|
|    Jen|      |
+-------+------+
```